# Can you record accessed methods in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm retroactively documenting and writing unit tests for some C# code. I would like to determine what code is actually being used and when.

In Visual Studio 2012, is there a way to record all the methods accessed and in what order while walking through specific scenarios?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Visual Studio Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9z62c29.aspx) will give you the time spent in each method, and let you inspect the call heirarchy. I don't know if it will give you the exact order they were called in though.

**EDIT**: Apparently attaching the profiler to a running unit test is [harder in VS2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12027885/how-to-profile-unit-tests-in-visual-studio-2012).

Answer (score 1):

You could run your application with a [profiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927/what-are-some-good-net-profilers) attached, which will give you all accessed methods, call chains,  counts, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to execute a test method that make sure that a particular method on a class was invoked ?  If so i dont know of a way to do it in VS alone, but you can use a mock framework to create dependency mocks and check values on them.  Here is a snippet of a unit test:

```
 [TestMethod]
        public void HttpPostPrivacyPolicyFacadeSvcErrorTest()
        {
            var controller = ControllerHelper.GetRouteController();
            controller.Session[SessionVariable.User] = new UserInfo() { UserName = Config.Data.Username };

            var idmSvcMock = new Mock<IUserServiceDAO>();
            var facadeSvcMock = new Mock<IFacadeSvcDAO>();

            //setup the facade mock to throw exception to simulate FacadeServiceException
            facadeSvcMock.Setup(x => x.SetPrivacyAcceptanceStatus(It.IsAny<UserInfo>())).Throws<Exception>();
            var userCollectorMock = new Mock<IUserInfoCollector>();
            userCollectorMock.Setup(x => x.GetUserInfo()).Returns(new UserInfo() { UserName = Config.Data.Username });




            controller.FacadeSvc = facadeSvcMock.Object;
            controller.UserServiceDAO = idmSvcMock.Object;
            controller.UserCollector = userCollectorMock.Object;
            controller.DefaultErrorId = "Route_errors_Unabletoprocess";

            //action
            var res = controller.Privacy(new FormCollection());

            //assert
            //make sure we go to the right controller, action, with the correct params.
            res.AssertActionRedirect().ToController("Errors").ToAction("Index").WithParameter("id", "Route_errors_Unabletoprocess");
            //did we call setprivacy once on the mock?
            facadeSvcMock.Verify(x => x.SetPrivacyAcceptanceStatus(It.IsAny<UserInfo>()), Times.Exactly(1));
```

In the test above i check that SetPrivacyAcceptance was invoked once and only once on my facadeSvcMock instance.  More on moq here: [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/)

this block of code is actually checking how many times SetPrivacyAcceptanceStatus was invoked:
//did we call setprivacy once on the mock?
            facadeSvcMock.Verify(x => x.SetPrivacyAcceptanceStatus(It.IsAny()), Times.Exactly(1));

the It.IsAny() is the one parameter to that method, so the line above says basically "For any input parameter of type UserInfo verify that we invoked SetPrivacyAcceptanceStatus exactly once."