# How can I use the sampling technique for profiling a Visual Studio 2012 unit test?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, profiling

When I use the [Profile Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12027885/how-to-profile-unit-tests-in-visual-studio-2012) command to profile a unit test in Visual Studio 2012 Update 1, the instrumenting profiler is used. This profiling technique has *way* too much overhead (100:1) to be useful in my application. How can I configure Visual Studio 2012 to profile my unit test(s) with the sampling profiler instead?

Comment: To down-voter, this is an interesting question about a specific programming problem that is solvable in the scope of an SO question, it is clear and understandable, why the downvote?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Best guess someone just doesn't like me, considering at the same time I received a downvote on one of the most extensively detailed Q/A posts I've ever put here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15263761